# Как программно показать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Как это сделать вручную:

1. Выполнить => control folders
2. Выберите вкладку Вид => снимите галочку с пункта "Скрывать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов", нажмите ОК

Как это реализовать программно?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68272/discussion-on-question-by-user3209------).

Comment: Если не сможете писать в чате — ответьте мне в комментарии, постараюсь помочь вам. )

Comment: regmon + выполнение указанных действий, потом - анализ обращений к реестру. Думаю, так станет ясно что и куда писать.

Comment: Меняйте значение параметра реестра **HideFileExt**
 ветви "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" на **0**. [https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-determine-if-93db8bff

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий, но нерекомендованный сообществом способ.

```
        internal static void ShowFileExtensions()
        {
            var subRegPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
            var parName = "HideFileExt";
            var parValue = 0x00;

            try
            {
                using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(subRegPath, true))
                    key.SetValue(parName, parValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

                Refresh(); // Refresh Windows explorer
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        internal static void Refresh()
        {
                var CLSID_ShellApplication = new Guid("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000");
                var shellApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ShellApplication, true);

                var shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(shellApplicationType);
                var windows = shellApplicationType.InvokeMember("Windows", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shellApplication, new object[] { });

                var windowsType = windows.GetType();
                var count = windowsType.InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, windows, null);
                for (var i = 0; i < (int)count; i++)
                {
                    var item = windowsType.InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, windows, new object[] { i });
                    var itemType = item.GetType();

                    var itemName = (string)itemType.InvokeMember("Name", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, item, null);
                    if (itemName == "Windows Explorer" || itemName == "File Explorer") // "File Explorer" for Win8 or up.
                        itemType.InvokeMember("Refresh", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, item, null);
                }
        }
```